# Is there a way to send Telnet commands in batch using C# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, telnet

What are my options if I want to send data to a telnet server in a batch. I am using c# and .net framework 4.0.

Does anything like sending data to telnet server in a batch mode exist? I know what to expect from server after I send it a command.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with C#?

Comment: My program that wants to run telnet commands in a batch mode is written in c#. I want to read the batch command file from my program and execute the commands in file. I hope this clears up my question.

Comment: OK, but what are you having problems with?  Have you written any code? What do you have so far?  This does not sound like a question, it sounds like you want someone to write it for you, SO is the wrong place for that, post some code and we will answer a question.

Comment: I am not looking for code. I am looking for ideas on how best to approach this problem. I still have to write code for communication with telnet server I will pots it here once I have that part written. right now I am thinking of reading one line at a time and send it over to server and wait for response. If I get expected response I send over the next command.